# R dplyr date filter based on another variable

Tags: r, function, filter, rstudio

I am trying to filter the rows based on dates only up to the row where the response is **"Yes"** i.e. first yes or the earliest yes. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Date <- c("1/2/2018", "1/3/2018", "1/4/2018", "1/5/2018", "1/6/2018", "1/7/2018", "1/8/2018")
Response <- c("No", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes")

df <- cbind(Date, Response)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming, you want to keep the first "Yes" response, you can do:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(Date, Response, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df %>%
  filter(cumsum(lag(Response, default = "") == "Yes") < 1)

      Date Response
1 1/2/2018       No
2 1/3/2018       No
3 1/4/2018       No
4 1/5/2018      Yes
```